# Typescript generic interface with union type

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, union-types, generic-type-argument

I want to use an interface with generic union types like this:

```
interface IOperator {
  <U>(a: U[], b: U[] | U): boolean
}

export const intersects: IOperator = (a, b) => a.some((el) => b.includes(el))
export const includes: IOperator = (a, b) => a.includes(b)
```

However, TS gives me error on both regarding one of the union types:

```
Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'U | U[]'.
  Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'U'.
```

How do I typecast properly here?

I tried:

```
export const intersects: IOperator = (a, b) => a.some((el) => (b as U[]).includes(el))
```

However, that gives me an error:

```
Cannot find name 'U'.
```

So how to handle generic union types?

I know that for the `intersects` method the types for input `b` should only be arrays and for the `includes` method the types for input `b` should never be arrays. The idea for the interface is to not repeat myself as I have plenty of methods where some require `b` to be an array and others to not be an array. I'd try to avoid to create two separate interfaces.

Thank you!

Comment: That TS error is *correct*; if `b` is `U` not an *array* of `U`, it (probably) won't have an `includes` method.

Comment: Instead of typecasting you need to check if `b` is an array.

Answer (score 1):

I think:

```
export const intersects: IOperator = (a, b) => a.some((el) => Array.isArray(b)&&b.includes(el))
```

should work. Otherwise, b might not be an Array of type U, so that includes is not available.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with using casting here is if the value of `B` doesn't match your casting, you'll have a runtime error. That being said, your use case may be valid and we just don't have the context available to see it. Otherwise, you may want to do a runtime check as suggested by some of the comments to your post.

This solution uses `function` to give you access to `U`, and then assigns the function to a `const` so you can type check that your function signature matches your interface.

```
interface IOperator {
  <U>(a: U[], b: U[] | U): boolean
}

function _intersects <U>(a: U[], b: U[] | U): boolean {
  return a.some((el) => (b as U[]).includes(el));
}
export const intersects: IOperator = _intersects;

function _includes <U>(a: U[], b: U[] | U): boolean {
  return a.includes(b as U);
}
export const includes: IOperator = _includes;
```